# C++ Read line by line file with class

Tags: c++

I need help. I want to write program that open file where are questions and read question by question, question in files start with < and end with > how to do that with class ?
I wanted program to go one question then after you answer you get next question.
for now i did this: 
`

```
int main() {
  ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("21fundamentalvariabletypes.txt");
  while (myfile){
    int i = 1;
    string strInput;
    getline(myfile, strInput);
    if (strInput == "<") {
      cout << i << ".";
      i++;
    }
    if (strInput == ">") {
      cout << endl;
    }
    else {
      cout << strInput << endl;
      i++;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and i get this on screen:

1.<
sta je ispravan nacin deklaracije promenljive?
- a = 4;
* int a;
- int a = 4;
- int a = 4

1.<
Povezati ispravan par?
- 1 a a
- 2 b b
- 3 c d
- 4 d a
* 1->3
* 2->3
* 3->4
* 4->1

Why doesnt i++ work, and why do i have 1.< for the first time. But when i dont put `if ( strInput == ">" )`etc. then i have 1. and then question

Comment: We aren't going to write a whole program for you. Write up your logic, and ask any technical questions here.

Comment: You are asking for a tutorial of a thing you could easily find on Google

Comment: look at `fopen`, `fgets`, `fclose` all on manual page #3

Comment: ok i put something where i am stuck now, sorry first time asking question here.

Answer (score 0):

well, if you want to read question by question, you can do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < line.size(); i++){
    if(line[i] == "<") break;
}
bool foundEnd = false;
int j = i + 1;
while(1){
    for(; j < line.size(); j++){
        if(line[j] == ">"){
            foundEnd = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!foundEnd) {getline(myfile, line); j = 0;}
    else break;       
}
return the whole text from i to j
```

step by step you can concat the lines from i to j and get your question

Answer (score 0):

why you create string `input` and `i` inside the loop? it means after each read of line these variables will be reset so declare them outside the loop.

in your case you can read only a single character each time as long as the question may contain more than one line so each input of this character will be scanned whether it is `<` or `>` the first makes a logical variable true as a sign of the question has begun and the latter is a sign of end of question which it Xors the `isBegin`.

and make an array of questions and feel it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{

    char c; 
    bool isBegin = false;
    string sQuestion[10];

    ifstream in("data.txt");

    int i = 0;
    while(in >> c) // read character by character
    {
        if('<' == c) // if so then it's a sign of beginning of question so set the logical variable isBegin to true
        {
            isBegin = true; // set it to true
            continue; // in order not to add '<' to the question    
        }
        else
            if('>' == c) // if so it is a sign of end of question
            {
                isBegin = false; // so set it to false
                i++; // move to next quesiton and store it in the next element in the array
            }
        if(isBegin)
            sQuestion[i] += c; // filling the question
    }

    // checking
    for(int i(0); i < 10; i++)
        cout << sQuestion[i] << endl;

    in.close();

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

- if you want you can read the file for the first time to count the number of questions then create a dynamic array of questions and last rear the file again filling it with each question.

Comment: @Zolak94: what spacing?

Comment: when i start code he load everything but there are no space between words.